# Making a simple HTML calculator issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math

I am learning Javascript and I am trying to make a simple HTML calculator where 2 prompts appear asking for numbers to add. Anytime I execute I get just the 2 numbers added together like 2 + 2 = 22, I did something wrong because I would want the response to be the right answer. Thanks so much!

'use strict';

```
let txt = prompt('Please enter your calculation');
let cal = prompt('And the other one');
```

let orange = txt;
let apple = cal;

```
alert(orange + apple);
```

Comment: You need to convert into integer or float as they are strings

Answer (score 2):

Your prompt inputs (txt and cal) are strings... you need to parse them to integers

```js
let txt = prompt('Please enter your calculation');
let cal = prompt('And the other one');
let orange = parseInt(txt); let apple = parseInt(cal);

alert(orange + apple);
```

if you also want to add floats, use parseFloat() instead of parseInt()